# hover colour transition slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link that changes colour when mouse hovers over it and i am fully conformable with the coding for this however i would like the however effect to slide down as oppose to just change colour. how is this possible with css. I have looked around stack overflow but only able to find instances where people use background images and alter the its position. Is that the only way to make this possible?

It is difficult to articualte what i am trying to achieve but it is on show on this website weblounge.be the effect that i am trying to achieve is on the two links on the homepage

```css
#contactlink {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 11px 51px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
          transition: .2s;
  margin-left: 78px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
          transition: .2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
#contactlink:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
          transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll" id="contactlink">Let's talk</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6t3quy4w/5/

Comment: it's possible, you can use a gradient from the new colour to the original colour and animate the back position property

Comment: can you fiddle your code

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/xejsM/52/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6t3quy4w/

Comment: white-on-white .. mmh. maybe you can learn stuff from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Why do you have `text-decoration: none;` twice?

Comment: @flowtron have edited jfiddle

Comment: The white on white is because on my webpage there is actually a background image - that was my fault for not altering the code for the purpose of the question. Apologies. It is difficult to articualte what i am trying to achieve but it is on show on this website weblounge.be the effect that i am trying to achieve is on the two links on the homepage

Comment: check here http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Answer (score 2):

The website you linked does theirs by having the `:before` pseudo-element transition its scale over top of the button. It also required having a `span` inside the button so that its `z-index` could be set on top of the `:before` element. Here is an example:

```css
a.color-change {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

a.color-change:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #777;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transform-origin: center top;
  z-index: 0;
}

a.color-change:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a.color-change span {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="color-change"><span>Hover Over Me</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your using whit on white, anyway based on my understanding i have provide some thing for you

```css
#contactlink {
    background: #1568b6;
    color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: normal;
 padding: 17px 20px 16px 20px;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-transition: background .15s;
 -moz-transition: background .15s;
 -ms-transition: background .15s;
 -o-transition: background .15s;
 transition: background .15s
}
#contactlink span {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-transition: color .25s;
 -moz-transition: color .25s;
 -ms-transition: color .25s;
 -o-transition: color .25s;
 transition: color .25s
}
#contactlink:before {
      background: #6c6c6c;
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
 -moz-transform: scale(1, 0);
 -ms-transform: scale(1, 0);
 -o-transform: scale(1, 0);
 transform: scale(1, 0);
 -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
 transform-origin: center top;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
 transition: all .25s ease-out
}
#contactlink:hover:before {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 -o-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1)
}
```

```html
<a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll" id="contactlink">
    <span>Let's talk</span>
</a>
```

Comment: The white on white is because on my webpage there is actually a background image - that was my fault for not altering the code for the purpose of the question. Apologies. It is difficult to articualte what i am trying to achieve but  it is on show on this website https://www.weblounge.be the effect that i am trying to achieve is on the two links on the homepage.

Comment: thats fantastic. thank you. didn't no where to start with that but at least now i know where/what i need to read up on. I guess this revolves around adding a span to the link and being able to apply z-index.